# How to import data from a single sheet into multiple SQL tables

Tags: excel, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have a single Excel file with only 1 sheet that has below structure:

```
c1  c2  c3      c4      
1   2   4.00    5       
45  67  89.00   67      
1   2   4.00    5       
45  67  89.00   67      
1   2   4.00    5       
45  67  89.00   67




c1      c2  c3      c4      c5      c6
abc     78  68      90      65      iti
nmbasd  67  89.00   45.00   34.00   iou
asd     89  45.00   23.00   90.00   uags
abc     78  68      90      65      iti
nmbasd  67  89.00   45.00   34.00   iou
asd     89  45.00   23.00   90.00   uags
abc     78  68      90      65      iti
nmbasd  67  89.00   45.00   34.00   iou
asd     89  45.00   23.00   90.00   uags
abc     78  68      90      65      iti
nmbasd  67  89.00   45.00   34.00   iou
asd     89  45.00   23.00   90.00   uags
```

I would like to store the first 6 rows of data into staging table and then store the rest of the rows into some other SQL table.
Could you please advise if this is possible in SSIS and how?

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do is not recommended. Individual file loaders are designed with the intent that a file only contains a single data set.

In your example, there are two data sets in the file. These data sets should be separated into two separate files. From there, you can load them individually and send the data to whatever destination your scope requires.

It is possible to load multiple data sets from one file into multiple data source using a script task. But, again, this is not recommended because you would be stuck determining that data range applies to each data set. This becomes problematic if the range is dynamic (i.e., changes). It would probably require a lot of error checking and testing.